# Problem producing an Altair Stacked Area Chart

Tags: python, altair

I'm trying to produce a similar Stacked Area Chart similar to the one below that's in the Altair Example Gallery ... which I can reproduce in my Jupyter notebook:

[image: jupyter notebook example]

I have similar data but instead of iso dates, I have YYYY-WW type of data that aggregates on the iso week.

As you can see from the chart, it doesn't seem to pickup on the "circulation_type" from the data, and I'm not sure why?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

UPDATE:
Thanks to @jakevdp I fixed my mistake of using the `source` variable instead of the `df` variable for producing my chart.

Here's an updated code block that I ended up using to produce the chart:

```py
alt.Chart(df).mark_area().encode(
    alt.Y('count:Q',
          scale=alt.Scale(domain=(0, 300000),
                         zero=True)
         ),
    alt.X("iso8601_week:T",
         ),
    color="circulation_type:N"
).properties(
    title='Checkin and Checkout Per Week',
    width=1300
).configure_title(
    anchor='start',
)
```

and then this is the output:
[image: chart output]

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is difficult to guess what the problem might be. Also, please do not paste screenshots of code; instead paste the text of the code in your question.

Comment: Thanks @jakevdp ... I was hoping maybe it would just be some obvious that I was missing. I'll post an update with code and sample data later

Comment: Now that you say it... I suspect the issue is that you loaded your data into a variable called `df` and constructed the chart from a variable called `source`.

Comment: yeah, so ... that was it exactly! ... thanks @jakevdp ! 

Although, I had to play around with the scales... I'll update the original. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Solved in the comments, the OP was plotting another variable that what they intended.